# How can i restrict Facebook Login to one account?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am enabling Facebook login/logout in my game so I can save the player's progress. Currently, when I authorize login with Facebook, the user can simply logout of one account and login with a different one *(which will save the game progress for multiple different accounts).* How can I make Facebook detect a previous login took place, and to prompt the user to continue with the previously logged in account?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the user id of the first logged in user account to `PlayerPrefs`. Whenever, player tries to login again, you can check if the id matches with the id in the `PlayerPrefs`. If it doesn't match, you can call logout function from code.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. That seems like a good suggestion. But I have seen a lot of games that automatically detects if there has been a login (on the facebook sdk side) and prompts the user to continue with the previously logged in account (although the user clicked the logout button). Do you have any idea how is that achieved? p.s. I apologize for the late reply and thank you again for your answer.